# Display in the child node content from the parent node

Tags: 6, nodes, taxonomy-terms

i'm new to Drupal 6 and i have a specific question, which can't be solved so far.
In my project i'm working with a Taxonomy menu module. So the menu structure is shown below.

Item1
-Subitem1 (Node1->Content_type1)
--Subsubitem1 (Node2->Content_type2)
--Subsubitem2 (Node3->Content_type2)

I also have 3 articles of different content types, which are associated with sub and subsubitems (See the structure above).
In Node2 and Node3 i must to display some content taken from the parent Node1 (title, image and file field). And i have to do this in each node, which has a content_type_2.

I'll be very thankful if you could provide me some information, which helps better understand and solve my problem.

Comment: Does Views in Drupal 6 allow you to add relationships the way it does in 7? If so, that's how you do it.